# how to make ionic 3 redirect to app after login using google account?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, google-plus, google-signin

I want to ask what shall i do to make my ionic 3 app came back to app when login using google account.

I have configure it and it is making login successfully but the web view is redirect to google.com home page and not back to app as usual

here is my code:

```
this.googlePlus.login({}).then(result => {
  console.error("LoginWithGooglePlus success: ", JSON.stringify(result));
  console.log("Google userId: ", result.userId);
  console.log("Google displayName: ", result.displayName);
  console.log("Google email: ", result.email);
  console.log("Google givenName: ", result.givenName);
  console.log("Google familyName: ", result.familyName);
  this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage, {}, { animate: true, animation: 'ios-transition' });
}).catch(error => {
  console.error("LoginWithGooglePlus error: ", JSON.stringify(error));
});
```

I want to mention that i used this code before on another application and it is working well, but now there is nothing happen, it is login and redirect to google plus directly without back to app !

Waiting for help, thanks

Comment: Hi, please share some code to get help ;)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
import {AlertController, App, ViewController, Events, NavController, LoadingController, Platform} from 'ionic-angular';

constructor(public http: Http,
                public app: App,
                public platform: Platform,
                public loadingCtrl: LoadingController,) {
        console.log('Hello Google Service Provider');
    }

this.app.getRootNav().setRoot('HomePage');
```